# Practical considerations when designing Android layout, getLeft() (relative) vs View.getLocationOnScreen() (absolute)?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollview

Let's assume I have a basic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container">

    <com.example.ScrollingView 
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/scrolling_view"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    <FrameLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

In my scrollManager, I have an EdgeEffect to show when you hit the edge of the scrollable area.  The left and right edges of the EdgeEffect are calculated like this:

```
View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrolling_view);
int containerWidth = scrollView.getContainerWidth();
int leftEdge = scrollView.getLeft(); // this is relative to parent, so returns 0!
int rightEdge = leftEdge + containerWidth;
// EdgeEffects are correctly drawn after this
```

The layout_container is drawn in a ListView. If it's the only item in the view, all of this code works fine since getLeft() returns the leftX relative to the parent view, which is 0, and just happens to correspond to the left side of the screen.

However, let's say I add another view to the left of scrolling_view that is 100px wide.  Suddenly, all this code goes to crap:

```
View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrolling_view);
int containerWidth = scrollView.getContainerWidth(); // 500px
int leftEdge = scrollView.getLeft(); // this is relative to parent, so returns 0.  however, its absolute position is now 100.
int rightEdge = leftEdge + containerWidth; // this now stops 100px short of the right edge of the screen
// EdgeEffects drawn after this all shifted 100px to the left
```

So my proposed solution is to change scrollView.getLeft() (which is relative to the parent view) to view.getLocationOnScreen() (which is absolute).

```
View scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scrolling_view);
int containerWidth = scrollView.getContainerWidth();
int[] posXY = new int[2];
scrollView.getPositionOnSreen(posXY);
int leftEdge = posXY[0];
int rightEdge = leftEdge + containerWidth;
```

I've tested this out pretty quickly and it seems to work flawlessly on both phones and tablets in landscape and portrait mode.

My questions:

1. Am I making my code more brittle by using an absolute XY instead of
   a relative XY?
2. Would it be better to get scrollView's parent and
   then call getLeft() on the parent instead?
3. Are there any other things I should take into consideration when using getLeft() vs getLocationOnScreen()?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you need `leftEdge` / `rightEdge` for?

Comment: It's used by some Canvas draw operations elsewhere in the code to add some fancy graphical effects.  I didn't include all that to keep the examples here simple, but long story short is that leftEdge and rightEdge need to stay.

Comment: so do Canvas drawing in your ScrollingView,  then left is always 0 and right is always getWidth()

Comment: While I agree that this would also be an option, without getting into too much detail, suffice to say that it would be a much, much larger change than the one I proposed.  For such a minor issue, I can't really justify the amount of refactoring required to make that work.